# How to fix Expecting 'STRING' error in JSON

Tags: android, json, getjson

I want use this **json** in my application :**Json** Link : [Google JSON](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C&language=fa&components=country:IR&location=35.6970118,51.2097313&radius=500&key=AIzaSyAMPXErR9Hlpj3u89eeJWq3iN5YxcmETGg)

But when check this json in https://jsonlint.com/, show me this error :

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   predictions: [{         d
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: this is valid json

Comment: the JSON you have shared is completely fine there are no errors in that

Comment: this is a valid json. copy all the json string and check it

Comment: use double quotes for strings   {"predictions":[ {....} ,{....},... ]    };   and https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C&language=fa&components=country:IR&location=35.6970118,51.2097313&radius=500&key=AIzaSyAMPXErR9Hlpj3u89eeJWq3iN5YxcmETGg is valid

Comment: @Abhishek, please see this image : https://image.ibb.co/mkJ5hk/8698r46tjy.png i copied all json

Comment: @mhtb,please see this image : https://image.ibb.co/mkJ5hk/8698r46tjy.png i copied all json

Comment: @user814...  double quotes was missing

Comment: @Raj, can you help me how can i fix it? please send me full code, please

Comment: @user8140110  R u call json using link or asset file

Comment: @Raj, i want create model of this json in this site : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  for android. but not show me model and just show error

Comment: The JSON which you have shared is completely valid I have checked it on the jsonlint as well it is showing valid json if you want Model classes of this json I can give you those personally

Comment: @Abhishek, can you send me code? or help me ? please

Comment: I can do both the things

Comment: @Abhishek, thank you my friend. i will wait. please help

Comment: There will be 6 Model classes generated with this JSON

Comment: share your mail id I will share classes with you

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to input a [proper JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

With your example :

```
{"prediction":[{"bla":1},{"blabla":2}]}
```

Every key of your JSON has to be string, thus in double quote.

EDIT:
Here s a snippet of your JSON with the proper syntax.

```html
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "ورزشگاه آزادی, تهران, استان تهران, ایران",
         "id" : "f030ac8db2df64a9bd389b5c269be00409840c11",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 13,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJvQwav4v8jT8RsME5g1S9_UA",
         "reference" : "CoQBgAAAAFECjj8o4B-jAZrNtY40NCaTH81J-XndLQ-P4kFuq3aEa29FZGgUcrbz0hHtunLebna-jpAh2ehtRC0eD1ulaHU8rtPseQyB28gcad1YcP7HYFMytycK6uweA5hFoO3tiANDv1tQHUCVCBxoai0TDZ04FkxY0FLwVc446zaPW14WEhA9-TzcUn_b8rA3bNWtlqOjGhQIfwx0iB7iVVLBPm0reMejSP9drg",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "ورزشگاه آزادی",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 13,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "تهران, استان تهران, ایران"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "ورزشگاه آزادی"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 15,
               "value" : "تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 22,
               "value" : "استان تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 35,
               "value" : "ایران"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "سینما آزادی, تهران, استان تهران, ایران",
         "id" : "5fb3c9e8466bb1a18edbbeed57235389984a8bdd",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 11,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJFXH3RU8Bjj8RoCA94pB7PEU",
         "reference" : "CoQBfAAAAOH1U3WpwebFo65m6QeJwPkayOhWRo_cg4lXTBTfwfHnUcX2MDclxWHyHDwe4B5GJU-RcIE1juUWYVezu4Pxw_J-L4zs3pREK1ZtxVypaOyH0ENJVMPTJ8B4fr_g7HBTn25yxRdURiLB923xntwsF1UQeuNWBYDozdDmt3ti6-TLEhCoyPVYCLlcaQOREARuadr3GhRF6XUIor8fQBF58dxLxVjxRSiEaw",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "سینما آزادی",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 11,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "تهران, استان تهران, ایران"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "سینما آزادی"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 13,
               "value" : "تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "استان تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 33,
               "value" : "ایران"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "برج آزادی, تهران, استان تهران, ایران",
         "id" : "341a8946768fa86f028ca90b5a2dca7f0417dd60",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 9,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJkS4scwX-jT8R9BX9vhfAvvw",
         "reference" : "CoQBeQAAAH7QIxqxsYQYwKW9aGcFBFS0HKAmBRY9QSaGPAVZE0BLSkpQyKyDKY7MnOP5RIl5muluoyFlZC_heOeTHmnh9rZlHlwgiVVarSnagr3vteeD3ZAFWbpYe3Yz3ZmRuiwkkZl0cjfb19WkhVtFQFE90RXWnqgc3ri80TH-1VC8VOgkEhCy7RMS1kEyCDlUZ11Tpsp6GhQOwQ6c5bKa79NnvORHb1507ebs-g",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "برج آزادی",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 9,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "تهران, استان تهران, ایران"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "برج آزادی"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 11,
               "value" : "تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 18,
               "value" : "استان تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 31,
               "value" : "ایران"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "آزادی, تهران, استان تهران, ایران",
         "id" : "d1b450bcc251fdbc988f73dda82edee1c26b9ded",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 5,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "EjnYotiy2KfYr9uMLCDYqtmH2LHYp9mGLCDYp9iz2KrYp9mGINiq2YfYsdin2YYsINin24zYsdin2YY",
         "reference" : "CnRnAAAAOa2un_nooAcX8DqkrTGAATrgaTGPFvMU9b0CIsgOOcheeEC1p6crUlogxuyIcAaSl_F3gEkFBHrjLGc_Hv5DI_VYGzRZzEt43p66H4TJO4u4DktgMpikv2LMRXruYelYcxN5B1BJA_E9FPjlkjo-xRIQUqTNt57jwTvWoGMueacfjBoU11gG1Wa-UmmYrd4IMn73nXX-8MQ",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "آزادی",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 5,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "تهران, استان تهران, ایران"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "آزادی"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 7,
               "value" : "تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 14,
               "value" : "استان تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 27,
               "value" : "ایران"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "route", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "آزادی منش, Zeytoon Street, تهران, استان تهران, ایران",
         "id" : "389a7144ee3434df3cc7a1504df73e55cf3ce903",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 5,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJOw-ir_L5jT8RYViiJk8Lkyo",
         "reference" : "CpQBiQAAADQjFMkeUtsnXsl1Hvbj6GpuGKT53jqIcHouGi8X-F9CZn6sE19NO_sJEgy1Zl7_IKcYnEEaFrSzfGvyclY7dem0b8UURVcHfcKfm-gn5bXc8wN2kdtp5TmRWHa8LMOnx3US85mygKGzwMztxGfisB1e2JcWtnFpyQGFsLyika279CNY_MhXyh_qhygfSicQ_RIQRazxTnLf3pVrdTGHhSl5ahoUQNSHgMD-ggRCZCcl3LcvU32PQSI",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "آزادی منش",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 5,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Zeytoon Street, تهران, استان تهران, ایران"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "آزادی منش"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 11,
               "value" : "Zeytoon Street"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 27,
               "value" : "تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 34,
               "value" : "استان تهران"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 47,
               "value" : "ایران"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Why google json is haven't "" ? how can i add this into all string?

Comment: I dont really know why the "" does not appear for you, but I gave you the full JSon with the proper syntax, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else gets here with a similar issue, I had the same error caused by a trailing comma and the json was expecting another field

```
{
  "case": {
    "field1": "fake value",    
    "field2": "fake value",
    "field3": "fake value",
    "field4": "fake value", < ---- this comma is not allowed
   }
}
```